# File in a folder for X time

Tags: c#, file, directory

here is a scenario:
I copy a file to a folder
and I expect it to be taken by other program.

is there a way to monitor the time that a file exists in a folder

I want to raise an event in case the file is in the folder over X time

Please advise what can I use to accomplish that

I had in mind using File system watcher and save the time of it created
and compare if the file exists after X time

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx may help you

Comment: [The fixed link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that @un-lucky posted.

Comment: If you've tried using the `FileSystemWatcher`, could you show us your code, and explain any specific issue you're still having?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use a `FileInfo` class to get the creation time of the file. I would also need to have a check to make sure that I don't constantly send an event for the file.

Comment: I agree with looking into FileSystemWatcher. You may however want to wrap it in a class to to help make it more robust as it has been known to randomly stop monitoring the path. Depending on your needs, you may want to check out https://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/tamed-filesystemwatcher/

Comment: this is a really interesting article, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about timeout, then simply check for it after copying. E.g. using a `Timer`:

```
var timer = Timer(5000);
timer.Elapsed += (s, a) =>
{
    // checking if file is still there
    if(File.Exists(...)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
timer.Start();
```

Comment: after a bit of investigation seems that this solution is the most relevant. much more correct approach, just check if the file is there after X time, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how precise you need to be, you could just have a process that checks the contents of the folder every so often and lets you know about any files that have been in the folder for too long.

Answer (score 0):

To list files in a directory you could use Directory.GetFiles as below.
Then iterate thru all the files checking for file age.

```
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp", "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        if (System.DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(System.IO.File.GetCreationTimeUtc(file)).TotalMinutes > 5)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TODO: Alert, file older than 5 minutes...");
    }
```